# How to model an artist and their work in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm thinking of moving a site (modernprints.co.uk) to [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) but want to know whether I will be able to model the relationships properly.

The site is for selling prints (i.e. paintings) by various artists, so an artist could have various prints connected to them.

Obviously the prints map to products, but how do I map them to artists? Should I be using collections?

Also, prints can be in a category such as 'abstract prints' or 'pop art prints', is this handled by collections?

Comment: collections, tags, or meta-data are all possibilities although this question is not appropriate for a coding forum and should be sent to shopify or you can read their manual to see how they handle categorization.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to have each artist as a vendor. You can then create dynamic collections which only show products which vendor equals to Mark Ryden.

Comment: Is it possible to attach extra information to a vendor i.e. artist image, artist biography?